# ¿Como cambiar el border radio y border color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente:
Necesito que que cuando se escriba algo en el input este cambie de color solo el input y tambie necesito redondear las esquinas exteriores, se supone son los inputgroup de bootstrap pero no funcionan lo saque de otra pagina

```css
     .input-group{
      display: table;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width:100%;
    }
    .input-group > section{
      display: table-cell;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      vertical-align: middle;  /* Safari */
    }
    .input-group-icon{
      background:#eee;
      padding: 0 12px;
    }
    .input-group-area{
      width:100%;
    }
    .input-group input{
      border: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 8px;
    }
```

```html
                <section class="input-group">
                <section class="input-group-area">
                    <input type= "number" placeholder="Cuenta" style="outline: 0;">
                </section>
                <section class="input-group-icon">
                    <img src="Assets/img/clipboard.png" width="17.5px" height="17.5px" align="center"/>
                </section>
              </section>
```

Comment: Que cambie qué del input? su color de fondo? o el color del borde?

Comment: @BetaM que cambie de color el borde cuando se escriba en el

Answer (score 2):

No me manejo con Bootstrap por tanto una aproximación al menos a como lo veo con CSS directo sería:

- Usar la pseudoclase `active` o la pseudoclase `focus` sin embargo queda el detalle que *estas no estarían reaccionando a cuando el usuario esta *escribiendo*.*

Lo anterior por que [leyendo sobre los input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) el efecto que veo se aplica ocurre cuando el usuario coloca precisamente el foco en algún input pero esto no necesariamente implica que el efecto se da cuando el usuario esta escribiendo, entonces creo que no es precisamente la solución que buscas.

Ahora

- Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

  - Declara una regla CSS que le quite el borde cuando el input esta activo y que le de el borde redondeado deseado (sería la clase **`algo`**)
  - Declara una segunda regla CSS que almacenará el color de borde y que de momento queda en pausa (*hasta que la agreguemos*), (sería la clase **`escribiendo`**)
- Ahora con JavaScript recuperamos al input por medio de una clase que le hayamos asignado
- Le damos un listener el evento `keyup` del input
- Cuando ocurra el evento antes mencionado, le agregamos a su lista de clases la segunda regla CSS que declaramos mas arriba para colocar el color de borde deseado (*que sería la clase **`escribiendo`**)

En el ejemplo notarás que el borde de color *teal* solamente se aplica cuando el usuario escribe y no cuando se coloca el focus del input.

```html
    <style>
      .algo {
        border-radius: 10px;
        outline: none;
      }
      .escribiendo {
        border: 2px solid teal;
      }
    </style>
    
    <input class="algo" type="text">
    
    <script>
      let texto = document.querySelector('.algo');
      
      texto.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        texto.classList.add('escribiendo');
      });
    </script>
```

**Enlaces de interés**

- [pseudoclases en CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)
- [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [evento keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event)